# C#. Убрать фон у изображения

Tags: c#, обработка-ошибок, picturebox, обработка-изображений

Я пишу программу на C#. Для этой программы я нарисовал картинку и вырезал у неё фон. Однако, при её открытии через PictureBox у неё появляется белый фон.
Вопрос: можно ли это как-нибудь обойти и убрать белый фон, чтобы не портить программу? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Поставь Paint.NET...

Comment: Ну так удали фон у картинки. И не верь Windows Photo Viewer'у - он не показывает белый фон, даже если он есть.

Comment: возможно оно отображает картинку в другом формате..проверь исходный формат картинки

Comment: Возможно, у вашей формы белый фон?

Comment: Вот специально проверил: Создал новый файл, удалил всё, нарисовал какой-то зигзаг на прозрачном фоне, сохранил в png; создал новое winforms приложение на C#, бросил на форму PictureBox, в Form_Load поместил код, присваивающий ему ту картинку и запустил. Фон серый, как у формы, никакого белого фона не появилось. ЧЯДНТ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, что бы фон отсутствовал в PictureBox, картинка должна быть без фона, например, в формате PNG, т.е. картинка загружаемая в него, должна быть с альфаканалом, в котором задана прозрачность для фона. Конкретнее - **формат картинки должен быть argb, 32 бита на пиксель**.

Вот скриншот у меня из проекта, где в PictureBox загружена картинка PNG с прозрачностью, причем поддержана она сразу, даже ничего не настраивал. Свойства основные тоже показаны.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно, на этапе разработки и при запуске это выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Получилось? Заработало?

Answer (score 0):

Всё так, только должно быть свойство `BackColor: Transparent`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это и есть все решение проблемы.

Comment: “В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша репутация достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению; на данный момент, пожалуйста, внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора.”

Answer (score -1):

У Вас фон совпадает с формой вот и все. Если картинку поставить над другой фон, то видно что он не пропал